# Link active effect not working while loading in new page

Tags: jquery

After click in page link, this jQuery doesn't remove active class from unclicked link and also not implementing this class in clicked item. It seems not working for page load. Is there any solution for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="active" href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
  <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Provided code works for me. But keep in mind that ```$.click()``` is deprecated and should be replaced with ```$.on('click', function() {...})```. Try debugging in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via this jQuery. This issue happened for page loading.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var path = window.location.href; 
    $('a').each(function() {
        if (this.href === path) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```